# vagrant cannot connect to virtual box

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtual-machine

When I `vagrant up` with a basic Vagrantfile with only those 2 lines configured :

```
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty32"
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
```

I see my virtual box opening, but then my vagrant log shows this line multiple times until timeout :

```
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
```

Then, some time after the timeout, the virtual box box is finally asking me for a login, but that was too long!

So I log with vagrant/vagrant. Then on my physical machine, if I "vagrant ssh". Nothing happens, until this :

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

What's wrong ? Any idea ?

(btw my port 8080 is free, and I also tried `vb.gui = true`,

and it's working with box `hashicorp/precise32`)

Comment: [Possibly relevant](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5186) github issue.

Comment: It might help to add `config.ssh.insert_key = false` to your Vagrantfile.  Run `vagrant destroy && vagrant up` to recreate your VM.  Not sure if that's gonna help, but I had one instance where that was all it took.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not working.

Comment: While my virtualbox trying to boot, I see lot of things happening, like lots of "Being: Loading..." and "Begin: Running..." lines, then "waiting 10 seconds for network device", then "waiting 120 seconds for network device",  then failing messages... then, ssh things, "Waiting for network configuration...", "Generation complete", further "Waiting for 60 more seconds for network configuration...", then vagrant timeout, then "Booting system without full configuration", then finally login screen.

Comment: Weird.  I'm out of ideas, sorry.  Useful info for other readers here might be: your vagrant version and your host environment. You should probably state those in your question.

Comment: My host environment : windows 7 (intel t6600 processor, so no virtualisation, so I use ubuntu/trusty32 instead of 64), vagrant version = latest.  Should I try an older vagrant version ?

Comment: So I guess my pc si too old (intel t6600 processor) for ubuntu/trusty32, even if ubuntu/trusty32 does not need hardware virtualization. Too bad, so I'll stick with "hashicorp/precise32"

Answer (score 8):

If you have a computer that supports hardware vir­tu­al­iza­tion, you need to enable it in the BIOS.

If you do not have a modern computer with a CPU that supports hardware vir­tu­alisa­tion, like in your case, you will have to stick to 32 bits boxes. That box, trusty32, is 32 bits so it should work.

But if it does not, you can try any of the things Piotr Banaszkiewicz describes in his blog post [here](http://piotr.banaszkiewicz.org/blog/2012/06/10/vagrant-lack-of-hvirt/). The post is a little bit old (2012) but we are talking about an even older CPU here (2009), so it may still apply.

As a summary, quoting here:

> - In the VirtualBox GUI select VM → Settings → System → Ac­cel­er­a­tion, then uncheck everything.
> - Go to the directory containing your VirtualBox VMs, then to your VM’s directory, then edit *.vbox XML file. Within the CPU tag children (like Hard­ware­Vir­tEx or PAE), replace every enabled="true" with enabled="false".
> - Turn off hardware vir­tu­al­iza­tion via Va­grant­file (config.vm.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--hwvirtex", "off"])
> - Check if number of CPUs for your Vagrant virtual machine is greater than 1. If so, go and change the count of CPUs in your *.vbox file to one.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but not working. "ubuntu/trusty32" still loads "without full configuration". Cannot "vagrant ssh".

Answer (score 7):

Have you modified anything inside the .ssh folder in the vagrant box ? I once deleted the know_hosts file and I was only getting:

```
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
```

Comment: thanks, but where is stored the vagrant  box ?   Is it in ~/.vagrant.d/boxes ?  Cause there I see box, but no .ssh folder.

Comment: I mean inside your guest O.S, in this case ubuntu/trusty32 and have you tried destroying the box and rebuilding it ?

Comment: Sorry, not working. I've tried destroying/rebuilding too.